# On which branch did the foo.py file last change?

Tags: git

Consider a Git repo with tens of branches. Short of looping through each branch and checking the log for a particular file, **how might I determine in which branch a file was last changed**?

For example: I'm on branch `master`, and `foo.py` was last changed in branch `master` on 2014-05-05. That same file was changed in branch `issue_42` on 2014-02-02 and in branch `issue_47` on 2014-07-07. **What command should I run to see that the file was last changed in branch `issue_47`?**

Comment: There is no such command.  Additionally, any scripting you attempt will likely have issues when it comes to handling merge commits.

Comment: It surely can be done with some heavy scripting, as you can fetch list of all commits, all 'heads' and then walk upwards for each head to see when the file was modified, stopping on first hit per branch, and optionally remembering inspected nodes so "grand-grand-(..)-parent" nodes are not constantly rechecked.. I certainly never seen a command for it.

Comment: Also, did you consider merges? if there was collision on that file and it was patched during the merge, then surely the patch is the newest content, but what if there was clean merge with no collisions? If `foo.py` was modified on monday on `foobar` branch, then when that branch is merged into `barbaz`, is the `barbaz` the newest version of that file for you, or `foobar`? Looking at `barbaz` it received the change today, so it's today's version of this file on that branch. Looking at content history, the change was on monday on `foobar`. Which branch would you consider having the newest file?